# PR and branches after change email

Tags: git, github

I faced with strange bihavior.
I have [fork](https://github.com/moteus/fusionpbx) of [FusionPBX](https://github.com/fusionpbx/fusionpbx) repo.
I create new branch and make [PR](https://github.com/fusionpbx/fusionpbx/pull/1613) and it was accepted.
But github did not display it as merge branch but just like regular commit.
Also it does not display it like merge in repo graph.
When I try remove branch from local repo I get.

```
error: The branch 'escene_phonebook' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D escene_phonebook'.
```

On local repo I make

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

This bihavior starts after I change my email on github and on local git config. I add new email to github account and set it as primary. Also I set this email in global settings on my machine. `git config user.email` display correct new address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's the new github feature of "merge-squash", which does not preserve link to the "merged" branch.

I believe the behavior you see does not relate to the email change.

PS: the commit is empty because your changes was already cherry-picked by mantainer. You can check [this blame link](https://github.com/fusionpbx/fusionpbx/blame/b4bb2e82219117af14208268adf24ee1237df226/resources/templates/provision/escene/e3xx/%7B%24mac%7D.xml#L110).

PS2: I'm not for sure but if you have left your older email, even as non-primary, your commits should be still shown as yours.

Comment: I already found this change in github and think the same. One strange thing that I can make same PR multiple times and it still display changes but there no one after first pr accepted. Really surprise behavior.